# Is there a way to not auto-generate the click event logic when a control is double-clicked in the Windows Forms designer?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Occasionally I will double-click a control on accident when moving them around in the designer. This creates a click event method in the associated class file along with the designer file. This can be undone, but ctrl+z seems to go back a step or two too far in the designer and is a minor nuisance. I don't have much need for the double-click shortcut and would prefer it removed entirely. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: in your button click event you could disable the button until the method has completed \ returned its data.

Comment: @SimonPrice He's talking about VS/the designer, not while actually running his app

Comment: _This creates a click event method_ It actually creates the [__default__ event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/default-control-events); for e.g. a TrackBar it is scroll.. Maybe you can fix your nervous mouse instead?

Comment: What version of VS are you using? If you are using 2017 above the autogenerated event handler there will be a place to see where it is referenced in the Designer.cs page. Take that line out and remove your event handler manually so the undo doesn't wipe out your work.

Comment: The only real way to get ahead on this question is to do a better job on describing why Ctrl+Z (aka Undo) is not working the way it works on most programmers' machines.  Give us a concrete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not worth the effort, but you could just inherit from the control you are using and set the DefaultEvent attribute to nothing.  For example:

```
[DefaultEvent("")]
public class ButtonEx : Button {

}
```

Now when you double-click on a ButtonEx control on the form in the designer, nothing happens.